# I am looking for the best way to customize a laravel default auth

Tags: laravel

I would like to customise Laravel Auth using Laravel 6.

For instance, I have a `users` table which has a column `status`.
It has two states: `0` or `1` (invalid/valid).

I want to get invalid users redirect to a certain page.

Are there any good articles? Please tell me how to implement this functionality?

I tried changing `RedirectIfAuthenticated`, but `Log::debug` did not show anything.

```php
class StatusVerify
{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Closure $next
     * @param null $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        /** @var Company $user */
        $user = $request->user();

        if ($user->status === 0) {
            view('auth.error');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

also added Kernel.php

```php
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'status' => \App\Http\Middleware\StatusVerify::class,

    ];
```

routes/api.php

```php
Route::middleware('status')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return view('auth.error');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues will be the strict comparison of the status:

```
class StatusVerify
{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Closure $next
     * @param null $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        /** @var Company $user */
        $user = $request->user();

        if (0 === (int) $user->status) { <-here convert the status to int
            return redirect('/page-where-to-redirect'); <- return was missing here + add the url
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Now on your route:

```
Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return view('auth.error'); //here you probably don't want to show an error if they have a valid status
})->middleware('status');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this article [here](https://www.larashout.com/backend-admin-authentication) it has two authentications one for admin and the default user.

Primarily you will need to start by updating the guards in `config/auth.php` and other files respectively explained in the article.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity I would do this to all of my methods, although its tiresome.

```
public function index(User $user,Request $request){
$user->where('id',$request->user()->id)->first();
if(user->status == 0){
return redirect('index')
}else{
return redirect('kicked')
}
}
```